# Strip final 0 off a python string

Tags: python, string, integer, subprocess, popen

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, subprocess, time
while True:    
    print subprocess.call("xsel", shell=True);
    time.sleep(1);
```

Takes an entry from the clipboard and prints it, every 1 second.

Result:

```
copied0
entry0
from0
clipboard0
```

I do not know why it returns the final 0, but it apparently stops me from using string strip (int has not strip), hence the 0 makes the string an integer?

How can one strip final 0 off the python string in the result above?

I'm a BASH scripter converting to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark pointed out, `subprocess.call()` does not do what you want

Something like this should work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys, subprocess, time
while True:
    p=subprocess.Popen(["xsel"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print p.stdout.read()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you XD - so I have to use a different subprocess.

Comment: And we have success: print subprocess.Popen(["xsel"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

Comment: I am assuming that you did need to be able to catch the output of xsel, and not just print it to the terminal

Comment: Return from code from subprocess was the problem. 0 is successful.

Comment: If you want to check the return code it is saved in `p.returncode`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: `subprocess.call` isn't returning a string, but an int -- that `0` you're seeing (after xsel's actual output).  Use, instead:

```
print subprocess.Popen('xsel', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable - I don't know what I'm doing wrong - perhaps its the way the call gives out its data.

Answer (score 2):

`"copied0".rstrip("0")` should work

Actually, you better do like this, It wont show return code to the screen

```
import os, sys, subprocess, time
while True:    
    _ = subprocess.call("dir", shell=True);
    time.sleep(1);
```

Comment: I need to strip it iteratively as above. I've created this from your post: entry = subprocess.call("xsel", shell=True);
 print "entry".rstrip("0entry") - seems to work but isn't that elegant.

Comment: Tried that - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rstrip' - the reason for the question.

Comment: No, the `0` IS from the python `print` command, it's the return code from subprocess.call ;-)

Comment: You're right! So just pass that variable to somewhere else. :-)

Comment: for future reference, added another answer to explain this

Comment: No i mean i've added another answer, since all current answers talk about string manipulation. But of course you're free to update your answer too ;).

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it is running "xsel" which is printing its results to stdout, then printing the return code (0) to stdout.  You are aren't getting the clip results from python.

You probably want subprocess.popen and to capture stdout.

Answer (score 2):

The `0` and new line feed at each line are the only things printed by the python print command, where zero is the shell return code from `subprocess.call`. The shell itself first prints it results first to stdout, which is why you see the word.

Edit: See the comments in S Mark's post for the epiphany.

Answer (score 1):

If the zero is always at the end of the string, and so you simply always want the last character removed, just do `st=st[:-1]`.

Or, if you are not sure that there will be a zero at the end, you can do `if st[-1]==0: st=st[:-1]`.